# Unable to stream large number of files from s3 using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, zlib

I am trying to read multiple compressed files from s3 parallelly, perform transformation operation, and upload it to back to s3. It's failing with the following error.

```
{
    "errorType": "Error",
    "errorMessage": "unexpected end of file",
    "code": "Z_BUF_ERROR",
    "errno": -5,
    "stack": [
        "Error: unexpected end of file",
        "    at Zlib.zlibOnError [as onerror] (zlib.js:180:17)"
    ]
}
```

Here is a code snippet for the above issue. Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

```
for (let inputKey of inputKeys) {
  let s3params = {
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: inputKey
  };
  let s3stream;
  if (metadata.compression === 'GZIP') {
    let unzip = zlib.createGunzip();
    s3stream = s3.getObject(s3params).createReadStream().pipe(unzip).pipe(ndjson.parse());
  } else {
    s3stream = s3.getObject(s3params).createReadStream().pipe(ndjson.parse());
  }
  // not sending the end event for each of the streams.
  s3stream.pipe(inputStream, {end: false});
  // after all the files are read, send the end event.
  s3stream.once('end', () => {
    --remainingFiles === 0 && inputStream.emit('end');
});
```

Comment: How many are you trying to do at a time?  If your server can't keep up and the TCP window size remains at zero for too long, the S3 servers will drop you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @brad. I'm trying to read 150 files each of which size around 1MB. The process just fails after running for 5 minutes.

Comment: Definitely sounds like it's taking far too long.  Try not downloading so many at once.